# "Error with request submission" on CreateSession method OpenTok .net SDK

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, video-streaming, opentok

I am using OpenTok .net SDK to create session but it's throwing error on **OpenTok.CreateSession(mediaMode: MediaMode.ROUTED)**
Error says, Error with request submission.

I have upgraded application framework to 4.6, enabled TLS1.2 in the application and  also the test endpoint (https://preview.opentok.com/tls-check.json) is returning tlsv1.2 but still OpenTok.CreateSession throwing error. Any Idea?

I have attached error snap for reference.
[image]